# Can alerts be configured on Azure Traffic Manager?

Tags: azure, azure-traffic-manager

I want to configure alerts on Traffic Manager's Monitor Status.The Monitor status such as "InActive/Degraded/Online/Stopped", I want to add an activity log or alert, if the status of Traffic Manager updates.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible as of now:

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/6237696-traffic-manager-failover-profile-alert

Its a feature which we are awaiting since 2014.